# Naming \NewDocumentCommands

Tags: xparse

As much as I tried to find a definition in the `xparse` document of what characters are and are not allowed in `NewDocumentCommnand`s, I did not find one. I know from experimenting that names like `myCommand2`, `myCommand.One`, `myCommand_Two` and `myCommand-Three` produce compilation errors due to the presence of `integers`, `.`, `_`, and `-` characters in the name, but what is the full story?

Comment: There is no difference with standard macro naming: either a single non-letter or a sequence of letters.

Comment: The syntax for command names is unrelated to whether you use `\def` or `\newcommand` or `\NewDocumentCommand` to define it, tex's scanner needs to parse `\zzzz` as a single token when it is used.